# Future.cancel(true) returns true but tasks not cancelled

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, future

On local machine, I have a runnable task which I am cancelling using future.cancel(true), which returns true and I see ThreadPoolTaskExecutor has no pending tasks.

However on a different environment (which is a container), I see future.cancel(true) return true, but ThreadPoolTaskExecutor does not accept new tasks, because previous tasks are not cancelled.

Any ideas why this can happen? Here is what I'm doing.

```
Task task = new Task();
Future<String> future = threadPoolTaskExecutor.submit(task);

// wait for some time
boolean val = future.cancel(true)

// still cannot submit more tasks

private class Task implements Callable<String> {
    @Override
    public String call() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
      return "value";
    }
}
```

Comment: What exception do you face when you try to submit more tasks? Is it java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException? Also, can you please share how is ThreadPoolExecutor created?

Comment: Please add the code where you create threadPoolTaskExecutor

Comment: This documentation will help to resolve your issue https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html?is-external=true#cancel-boolean-

Answer (score 0):

The JavaDoc could be clearer, but what `cancel` actually does is cancelling the future and optionally interrupting its thread. If this succeeds it returns `true`. However, there is no guarantee that the thread actually does terminate as a result of this. In the case of `mayInterruptIfRunning` this can happen if the thread does not properly handle `InterruptedException` in all places.

See e.g. the source code for [`FutureTask.cancel`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.java#L164-L182).